# Can Meteor-based-ios app access data from my own server?

Tags: meteor, server, meteor-ios

I'm new to Meteor and made a very simple meteor-based ios app for personal use and interest, which read data from MongoDB provided by Meteor. I have a quick question and I just want to make sure that I am not spending time on meaningless work.

What I have done is "meteor run ios-device", and it works pretty well that under the same network (wifi) the app on ios could read data from the localhost:3000 on laptop (Mac). Also, I have learned that it is easy to deploy a meteor app on my own server, just run "meteor build /path/to/buildFile --architecture..." and move the bundle to the server to set up; however, then I got confused about this: after the app is deployed to a server, is it possible that the app on ios also able to access to that server?

In short words, app ios works fine with localhost, so is there a way to make it works fine with web hosting so that the app does not need to connect to the same network as the host?

Note that I didn't purchase Apple developer account that could release app to AppStore, so I can only use "real machine debugging". Will this disallow me to make app on ios access the data from my own server?

Thanks for any advance!

**Update:**
I have successfully deployed my project on my own OpenShift server so that I could access it within any networks in browsers. So my point is how do I build an ios app for this project so that I can also access it in iPhone within any network. I have tired run "meteor run ios-device --mobile-server=[my own openshift server]:8000", and when I build the app for deploying I ran this "meteor build ~/some/path --server=[my own openshift server]:8000". This seems does not works. Still waiting for advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing one of the main use case of Meteor.

Refer to:

- [Meteor Guide > Mobile > Configuring your server](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#configuring-server-for-hot-code-push)
- [Meteor Guide > Mobile > Building for production](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#building-for-production)

To summarize:

When building your Meteor project, if you have `ios` and/or `android` platform(s), Meteor will require you to specify the `--server` option with the URL of the server where your Meteor server bundle will be deployed.

That way, your app will know where to connect to.

Note that you may not need to go through Apple App Store, as long as you do not need to distribute your app. You can simply use the Xcode project (generated by `meteor build`) to install your app directly on your iPhone.

Comment: Thanks for advising! Now I have successfully deployed my app to OpenShift, which is not a localhost so that I could access it in browsers with any networks. However the ios app still could not access to OpenShift. I used command "meteor run ios-device --mobile-server=xxx(openshift domain):8000", and when building the production I used "meteor build ~/some/path --server=xxx:8000". Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Well, nvm, you are right, everything went well now! Thank you very much.